# Cocos2dX endless map

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, tmx, tiled

i'm a newbie with cocos2dx, i'm trying to create a game using tilemaps with cocos2dx and tiled (.tmx), I don't know what if it's the good way to go, but I want to create an endless map, a game when you can run and run for ever if you want.
I was trying to use two tilemaps and repeat one next to each other without success (i'm still very limited in knowledge of cocos2dx :) ).
Did you recommend me this approach? if no, what do you recommend me?, if yes how can i put two tilemaps one next to each other?

Comment: you could have a look how it's implemented in kobold kit. Fair warning: the renderer is complex and in objective c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow this official tutorial to learn how to create good endless title map: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/tutorial/parkour-game-with-javascript/chapter7/en

Even this is a tutorial for javascript but the class used is the same. Hope it help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already solve the problem in a similar way. :)